# Table with a radio buttons doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create with HTML and CSS a pretty table with radio buttons near to rows names. I'm very new with CSS so I started to take some code around internet randomly until my table was good looking. This is my code:

```css
.attr-col {
  margin: 65px 0 0;
  float: left;
  width: 250px;
}
.attr-col ul {
  background: #f4f4f4;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 13px;
  border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
  border-width: 1px 0px 1px 1px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}
.attr-col ul li {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
  line-height: 45px;
  display: block;
}
.pt-table {
  padding-left: 200px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.pt-body {
  padding: 10px 0 0;
}
.pt-rows li {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #fff;
  border-left: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-right: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
}
.pt-rows li span {
  width: 24%;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  display: block;
  line-height: 45px;
  height: 45px;
}
.pt-rows li.title {
  background: #666;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #555;
  border-width: 0 0 2px;
}
.pt-rows li.title span {
  line-height: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: none;
  padding: 0 1px;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #444;
}
.pt-rows li span.pt-3x {
  width: 72%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="price-chart">
  <div class="attr-col">
    <ul>
      <div id="var">
        <li class="radio">
          <input type="radio" name="var" id="var1" value="V1" checked="checked" />Observation
        </li>
        <li class="radio">
          <input type="radio" name="var" id="var1" value="V2" />Income &#8364;</li>
        <li class="radio">
          <input type="radio" name="var" id="var3" value="V3" />Sold &#8364;</li>
        <li class="radio">
          <input type="radio" name="var" id="var4" value="V4" />Up (%)</li>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="pt-table">
    <div class="pt-body">
      <ul class="pt-rows">
        <li class="title"><span>category 1</span><span>category 2</span><span>category 3</span><span>category 4</span>
        </li>
        <li><span>-</span><span>-</span><span>-</span><span>-</span>
        </li>
        <li><span>-</span><span>-</span><span>-</span><span>-</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I left in the last 2 rows only row names to show that here the radio buttons work. While in the first rows dont work! I'm sure that the fault is of my CSS code, but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
.pt-table { padding-left: 200px; display: block; position: relative; }
```

to

```
.pt-table { margin-left: 200px; display: block; position: relative; }
```

```css
.attr-col {
  margin: 65px 0 0;
  float: left;
  width: 250px;
}
.attr-col ul {
  background: #f4f4f4;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 13px;
  border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
  border-width: 1px 0px 1px 1px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}
.attr-col ul li {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
  line-height: 45px;
  display: block;
}
.pt-table {
  margin-left: 200px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.pt-body {
  padding: 10px 0 0;
}
.pt-rows li {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #fff;
  border-left: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-right: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
}
.pt-rows li span {
  width: 24%;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  display: block;
  line-height: 45px;
  height: 45px;
}
.pt-rows li.title {
  background: #666;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #555;
  border-width: 0 0 2px;
}
.pt-rows li.title span {
  line-height: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: none;
  padding: 0 1px;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #444;
}
.pt-rows li span.pt-3x {
  width: 72%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="price-chart">
  <div class="attr-col">
    <ul>
      <div id="var">
        <li class="radio">
          <input type="radio" name="var" id="var1" value="V1" checked="checked" />Observation
        </li>
        <li class="radio">
          <input type="radio" name="var" id="var1" value="V2" />Income &#8364;</li>
        <li class="radio">
          <input type="radio" name="var" id="var3" value="V3" />Sold &#8364;</li>
        <li class="radio">
          <input type="radio" name="var" id="var4" value="V4" />Up (%)</li>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="pt-table">
    <div class="pt-body">
      <ul class="pt-rows">
        <li class="title"><span>category 1</span><span>category 2</span><span>category 3</span><span>category 4</span>
        </li>
        <li><span>-</span><span>-</span><span>-</span><span>-</span>
        </li>
        <li><span>-</span><span>-</span><span>-</span><span>-</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```